# Code::blocks неправильно отображает подсказки для std::vector

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl2

В данном случае textures - это std::vector структур. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я ввожу название вектора и нажимаю точку, выводится подсказка не об методах std::vector, а неизвестный _M_emplace_aux.[image]

На всякий случай:
Объявление структуры:

```
struct tx{
    SDL_Texture * walls;
    SDL_Texture * floor;
};
```

Объявление вектора:

```
vector <tx> textures(2);
```

Comment: используйте нормальную IDE

Comment: А почему вы думаете что должен? Иногда и кланг в саблайме фигню показывает... Что шланг г что кодблок.... Возьмите VS code Clion и тд

Comment: vs code может использовать clang. А может майкрософтовское. Clion (который вообще не понятно что), также активно использует clang.

Comment: Clangd в VSCode, особенно новый, очень даже хорошо работает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в саблайме он так себе..... а вс код много кушает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда изменил объявление

```
vector <tx> textures(2)
```

на

```
std::vector <tx> textures(2)
```